# unable to connect php to mysql on local system

Tags: php

I trying to connect php to mysql. I am not using any tool like (xampp or wamp). I have separately installed apache/php/mysql. Now I am trying to connect to my sql using following code but nothing happening. it just prints 'started'.

```
<?php
    echo 'started'."<br/>";
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root");       
    echo 'mysql connected'."<br/>";
    mysql_select_db("test");
    echo 'db connected'."<br/>";
mysql_query("CREATE TABLE MyTable (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
  FirstName CHAR,
  LastName CHAR,
  Phone INT,
  BirthDate DATE
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
)");
mysql_close ();
    ?>
```

Comment: Turn on PHP error reporting, you will get more info on how to fix it...

Comment: You're missing a comma between `BirthDate DATE` and `PRIMARY KEY(id)`.

Comment: If you're just learning MySQL, you should use PDO or mysqli, not mysql extensions. The latter are obsolete and deprecated.

Comment: @Salketer i started error reporting, but i couldn't see anything on console

Comment: `mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root") or die(mysql_error());`

Comment: @Charlie i tried already, still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: why dont just `echo 'started<br/>';` ??

Comment: @Charlie yes, noted :) but currently problem is something else. I am not even getting proper output. it doesn't have closing tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. turn ON your error reporting
2. check this line: `mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root");`
   if it prints just "started" it means somewhere you have a "fatal error". mysql_connect won`t stop the script execution if you just entered the wrong details (username/password/server address).
   some of the errors may happen if you haven't enabled the php_mysql extension in your php configuration file.